# Onitemclicklistener for adapter

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I have three listview inside a tab according to spinner.The spinner have 3 options "ALL" ,"PAYMENTS" and "EXPENSES". Actually there are two listviews ie; PAYMENTS and EXPENSES.The "ALL" option in spinner will show combine list of both PAYMENTS and EXPENSES. These two list views have single clickable items as shown in screenshot.(SP125-PAYMENTS, OE300-EXPENSE).If i click on single item(eg:SP125) of payment list it will go to paymentdetails activity and also if i click on single item(OE300) of expense list it will go to expensedetail activity. How to set onclick listner which will work on both thee list view?The click of item in "ALL" should be same even if it is clicked from its separate list("PAYMENT"or "EXPENSE").?

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), invoiceListData, Common.PREVIOUSPAYMENTS);
invoiceList.setAdapter(adapter);
(rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_card)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


final ArrayList<String[]>PaymentListData = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<String[]>ExpenseListData = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < invoiceListData.size(); i++) {
    if (invoiceListData.get(i)[6].equals("Payment")) {

        PaymentListData.add(invoiceListData.get(i));

        invoiceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent approvalDetailsIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ApprovalDetails.class);
                approvalDetailsIntent.putExtra(Common.APPROVALID, common.dataArrayList.get(position)[0]);
                approvalDetailsIntent.putExtra(Common.ENTRYNO, common.dataArrayList.get(position)[1]);
                startActivity(approvalDetailsIntent);
            }
        });

    } else if (invoiceListData.get(i)[6].equals("Expense")) {

        ExpenseListData.add(invoiceListData.get(i));


        invoiceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent approvalDetailsIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ApprovalExpenseDetails.class);
                approvalDetailsIntent.putExtra(Common.APPROVALID, common.dataArrayList.get(position)[0]);
                approvalDetailsIntent.putExtra(Common.REFNO, common.dataArrayList.get(position)[1]);
                startActivity(approvalDetailsIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}

Padapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), PaymentListData, Common.PREVIOUSPAYMENTS); //Global variable
invoiceList.setAdapter(Padapter);
(rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_card)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


Eadapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), ExpenseListData, Common.PREVIOUSPAYMENTS);
invoiceList.setAdapter(adapter);
(rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_card)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the `onClickListener` in your `onBindViewHolder` if you're using `RecyclerView` or in your `getView` if you're using `ListView` instead, inside your `CustomAdapter` class.

To do that, you need to have a way to differentiate whether the clicked item is of type `Payment` or `Expense`, then you can start a new activity accordingly.

Comment: @Daredevil You need to post your `CustomAdapter` code then

Comment: @Daredevil You should try to make the changes yourself. Else, you won't learn

Comment: @Daredevil Yea, the most I can provide is pseudocode. You can search online, there are a lot of great tutorials.

Comment: @Da_Pz bro help me.

Comment: @Da_Pz bro how can i add Onclickitem for InvoiceListData,PaymentListData and ExpenselistData by switch case?

Comment: @Daredevil You just set the `onClickListener()` to every responding view(the view that will respond when you click on it) of your `viewHolder` item when it gets bind, then start performing different actions based on the type in your `onClick()` method, like what `kumuthini`'s showed.

Comment: @Da_Pz bro is there any way to call arraylist usin switch case?so that i can call Onclicklistner inside each case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for loop to get all the values in the Main Activity, try Using **OnClickListener in Adapter** and pass the values from adapter.

```
                viewHolder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (invoiceListData.get(position).equals("Payment")){
                     /*Pass the payment detais*/
                     }
                   else if (invoiceListData.get(position).equals("Expense")) {
                    /*Pass the Expense detais*/
                     }

                   }
            });
```